# How to install standalone puppet on Redhat?

Tags: puppet, redhat

Can anyone suggest me the step by step process for standalone puppet installation on Redhat?

I was trying to install by following the below link https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html

But when I run `sudo yum install puppet` command, the following errors are coming:

> Error: Package: rubygem-json-1.5.5-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps) Requires: rubygems >= 1.3.7
>
> Error: Package: puppet-3.7.5-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs-products) Requires: ruby >= 1.8
>
> Error: Package: rubygem-json-1.5.5-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps) Requires: ruby(abi) = 1.8
>
> Error: Package: puppet-3.7.5-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs-products) Requires: ruby(selinux)

Comment: You have a problem with your `yum` repository configuration, but it's unclear exactly what.  If you are running a version of RedHat outside the 6.x series then you have configured the wrong puppetlabs repository.  Otherwise, you probably need to enable a RedHat repo that is currently disabled.

Comment: oO!, every answer got down-vote. I am scare to answer it.

Comment: Have you enabled optional channels? "CentOS and other community forks have several packages Puppet depends on in their main repos, but RHEL itself is split into channels. If you’re installing Puppet on RHEL, you’ll want to make sure the “optional” channel is enabled. Instructions are available here." https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html#step-1-enable-dependencies-rhel-only

Comment: @Anony, possibly all you need to do is enable the  `rhel-6-server-rpms` and / or `rhel-6-server-optional-rpms` repositories.

Answer (score -2):

The errors are indicating you the problems.

You need to install previously some packages to run puppet installation.

> > Error: Package: rubygem-json-1.5.5-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps) Requires: **rubygems >= 1.3.7**
>
> Error: Package: puppet-3.7.5-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs-products)
>   Requires: **ruby >= 1.8**
>
> Error: Package: rubygem-json-1.5.5-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
>   Requires: **ruby(abi) = 1.8**
>
> Error: Package: puppet-3.7.5-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs-products)
>   Requires: **ruby(selinux)**

Regards, David.

Comment: If that were all it was then yum would take care of it.

Comment: This answer should be removed - it is clearly not helping